# When using Corda OS where can I view the flow hospital data?

Tags: corda

When a transaction fails to make it to the destination node, where can I see those failed transaction data? I understand there is not a UI in the OS version. I am assuming there got to be somewhere in the DB or files system where this information is stored so Corda is able to retrieve it at a later time. If it's in a readable format, where can i find it?

Answer (score 1):

you can get a list of flows hospitalized by looking at the node_checkpoints table in the database. 
you can also fire the below command on the node terminal once you have started your node to get an idea of all flows which have been hospitalized.

```
run stateMachinesSnapshot
```

There is one un-published blog which I have written on flow hospital, you can take a look at the same as well.

https://medium.com/p/edc1b5a2f14/edit

Comment: Hi Sneha - Thank you and that does answer a part of what I am trying to do. I am trying to create a report of failed transactions so that the initiator can take appropriate follow on steps if after 'x' hours has passed and the flow is still in error. By running stateMachinesSnapshot I get an id. I am also looking for more info such as what is the destination (say PartyB), details of the user transaction (IOU details) that failed etc. Where do I see those details?