# java.io.NotSerializableException when running Corda 4.4 Enterprise Tools Explorer

Tags: corda

I get the following error (see image snapshot) when trying to run Corda Enterprise Tools Explorer 4.4 and connecting to a custom cordapp node.

Steps:

1. Double click on corda-tools-explorer-4.4 executable jar
2. Enter the host, port and credentials (see a screenshot of the login screen)

I get the following error (see screen shot below). 
net.corda.core.CordaRuntimeException: java.io.NotSerializableException: **net.corda.finance.internal.CashConfigDataFlow** was not found by the node, check the Node containing the CorDapp that implements net.corda.finance.internal.CashConfigDataFlow is loaded and on the Classpath

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version of node explorer you are referring to only works with the finance cordapp. You need to have the finance cordapp installed in the node.

However, we have recently done a beta release of a new node explorer, which supports custom cordapps.

You can download it here: https://github.com/corda/node-explorer/releases

For a demo check here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cn2lhS8pjRs

Comment: Thanks Ashutosh. I am looking at the enterprise explorer UI to troubleshoot hospitalized flows. I don’t see that option available in the beta version unless I am missing something here? Please advise.

Comment: The flow hospital is not part of the Explorer. In fact, there is no UI application available for the flow hospital currently.

Comment: Is the documentation wrong then?                                                                         
 From the docs: Flow hospital functionality is enabled by default in Master. No explicit configuration settings are required.

There are two aspects to the flow hospital:

run-time behaviour in the node upon failure, including retry and recovery transitions and policies.
visualisation of failed flows in the Explorer UI ----this is what I am referring to

Comment: Or refer to this link. At the end there is a subtopic called visualization which has a screenshot of the flow hospital triage. https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-enterprise/4.4/node/node-flow-hospital.html

Comment: Ah ok, my bad it's probably a new feature added to the original explorer. This was not extended to the new one in the beta release.

Comment: So how do I solve my issue? Am I stuck until someone fixes the beta to include flow hospital UI or someone fixes the enterprise node explorer to make it custom cordapp compatible?

Comment: This is the issue I am trying to solve for. Refer to my comments at the end of this SO thread:                                               
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62187251/when-using-corda-os-where-can-i-view-the-flow-hospital-data

Comment: The guess the only way to do that for custom cordapp is to use the CRASH Shell or a Client to fetch the information using the stateMachinesSnapshot/ stateMachinesFeed APIs.